# make git status show folders with modified files

Tags: git

I have a lot of modified files in my working tree. But I ONLY want to see what files are actually staged for commit so I don't accidentally push files that I'm still working on. How can I do this?

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the confusion -- if there's no way to just see the staged changes, then is it possible to only see a list of folders with modified files instead of all modified files?

Comment: Your title and question body ask two different questions.  Which do you want the answer to?

Comment: Good call! I've edited the question body. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the output of `git status`:

```
git status --porcelain | grep "^[MADRCU]" | cut -c 4-
```

The `--porcelain` option ensures backward-compatibility between different git versions and is similar to the `--short` output. The `grep` pattern handles different kinds of changes to files. See `git help status` for further explanation.

Comment: `cut -c 4-` removes the three characters from the beginning of every line, so that you get only the paths as output. Look a the format of `git status --porcelain` running it and check the format specification by looking it up in the manual (using `git help status`) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

git status will show you both, first the files that are staged for commit, then the modified files but not staged for commit

note that new files are always staged

You should avoid too many modified files, commit early and commit often

If you have a lot of unrelated changes that you need to track you should really look into branching

Comment: Hmm, I've run into problems with branching using drupal because drupal stores a list of enabled modules in the database. If I enable a module that's one branch then switch to another branch, drupal crashes. You're totally right that what I'm doing is NOT best practice, but I don't know how to make drupal play nice with branching...